# Number of partitions scanned(=32767) exceeds limit

Tags: hadoop, hive, partition

I'm trying to use Eel-sdk to stream data into Hive.

```
val sink = HiveSink(testDBName, testTableName)
.withPartitionStrategy(new DynamicPartitionStrategy)

val hiveOps:HiveOps = ...
val schema = new StructType(Vector(Field("name", StringType),Field("pk", StringType),Field("pk1",a StringType)))

hiveOps.createTable( 
  testDBName,
  testTableName,
  schema,
  partitionKeys = Seq("pk", "pk1"),
  dialect = ParquetHiveDialect(),
  tableType = TableType.EXTERNAL_TABLE,
  overwrite = true
)
val items = Seq.tabulate(100)(i => TestData(i.toString, "42", "apple"))
val ds = DataStream(items)
ds.to(sink)
```

Getting error: Number of partitions scanned(=32767) exceeds limit(=10000). 
Number 32767 is a power of 2....but still can't figure it out what is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: What do you have set for `hive.limit.query.max.table.partition`?

Comment: The question is...why would I need so many partitions when I'm just writing 100 items with the same partition keys? I need only one partition.

Answer (score 1):

[Spark + Hive : Number of partitions scanned exceeds limit (=4000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62180078/spark-hive-number-of-partitions-scanned-exceeds-limit-4000)

```
--conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false"
--conf "spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=false"
```