# Spark + Hive : Number of partitions scanned exceeds limit (=4000)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdp

We upgraded our Hadoop Platform (Spark; 2.3.0, Hive: 3.1), and I'm facing this exception when reading some Hive tables in Spark : "Number of partitions scanned on table 'my_table' exceeds limit (=4000)".

Tables we are working on :
table1 : external table with a total of ~12300 partitions, partitioned by(col1: String, date1: String) , (ORC compressed ZLIB)
table2 : external table with a total of 4585 partitions, partitioned by(col21: String, date2: Date, col22: String) (ORC uncompressed)

**[A]** Knowing that we had set this spark conf:
`--conf "spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive"`
We execute in spark :
[1] 
`spark.sql("select * from table1 where col1 = 'value1' and date1 = '2020-06-03'").count`
=> Error : Number of partitions scanned (=12300) on table 'table1' exceeds limit (=4000)
[2] `spark.sql("select * from table2 where col21 = 'value21' and col22 = 'value22'").count`
[3] `spark.sql("select * from table2 where col21 = 'value21' and date2 = '2020-06-03' and col22 = 'value22'").count`
=> Error on [2] and [3] : Number of partitions scanned (=4585) on table 'table2' exceeds limit (=4000)

**[B]** We solved the problem by adding this spark conf :

```
--conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false"
```

resulting in automatically activating  : `--conf "spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true"`

Re-executing in spark :
[1] and [2] => Success
[3]   => Error : `Number of partitions scanned (=4585) on table 'table2' exceeds limit (=4000)`

**[C]** To solve the error on [3], we set

```
--conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false" 
--conf "spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=false"
```

Re-executing in spark :
[3] => Success
on the other hand, if we recall [1] : performance is degraded, it takes so mush time to execute and we don't want that..

*In conclusion:*
In case [B], we think that a partition can not be of a type "Date", when it's a String it is OK.
But why ? What's going on ? Aren't we supposed to have a partition of other types than String type when partition Pruning is activated ?
Why does it work in case [C] ? and how could we solve case [B][3] without degrading performance of [1] ?

Hoping that it's clear, please let me know if you need other information!

Thank you if you can help or advise !

Comment: Can you verify the value of Hive configuration for `hive.metastore.limit.partition.request` ?

Comment: Yes, hive.metastore.limit.partition.request = 4000, and it had always been set to 4000.
But the issue is with Spark scanning all the partitions of the table when the request is to scan one particular partition...

Comment: what is the resolution for this ? spark is scanning all partitions for a hive table even after specifying one single partition